# Basic Oasis or Opam file for a simple OCaml project

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, opam, oasis

I am a new OCaml user. I have asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28810855/using-opam-to-manage-project-dependencies) to learn how to set up a basic OCaml project, but I still have issues. Jump to the end for a TL;DR

For instance, I am trying to learn Irmin. On the [home page of Irmin](https://github.com/mirage/irmin) I see I have to do

```
opam install irmin git cohttp
```

Doing so, I end up with Irmin version 0.8.3. Unfortunately, I cannot follow their examples, because apparently Irmin is at version 0.9.4, and it looks like the API has changed. So, I would like to start a clean project having as dependency just Irmin 0.9.4

First, I have set up an opam switch with

```
 opam switch install playground -A 4.02.1
```

to be sure to work on a clean slate. Then, I have created a basic `_oasis` file that looks like this

```
OASISFormat: 0.4
Name:        Playground
Version:     0.1.0
Synopsis:    OCaml playground
Authors:     Andrea Ferretti
License:     Apache-2.0
BuildTools: ocamlbuild

BuildDepends:
  irmin,
  irmin.unix,
  lwt,
  lwt.unix
```

and then I have copied the example from the Irmin homepage in `example.ml`.

```
open Lwt
open Irmin_unix
let store = Irmin.basic (module Irmin_git.FS) (module Irmin.Contents.String)
let config = Irmin_git.config ~root:"/tmp/irmin/test" ~bare:true ()
let prog =
  Irmin.create store config task >>= fun t ->
  Irmin.update (t "Updating foo/bar")  ["foo"; "bar"] "hi!" >>= fun () ->
  Irmin.read_exn (t "Reading foo/bar") ["foo"; "bar"] >>= fun x ->
  Printf.printf "Read: %s\n%!" x;
  return_unit
let () = Lwt_main.run prog
```

If I do `oasis setup` and then `ocamlbuild example.ml` I get a bunch of errors

```
W: Cannot get variable ext_obj
W: Cannot get variable ext_lib
W: Cannot get variable ext_dll
W: Cannot get variable ocamlfind
```

So in short my question is:

> What is the simplest way to set up a clean project that depends on Irmin 0.9.4, being sure that it is self-contained (it will not rely on preinstalled libraries other than those installed by the build process)?

Comment: Irmin is noted as 0.9.3 in the official repository. Is it a typo in your question or did you forgot to do a `opam update` for a long time?

Comment: he also might have some dependencies forcing him to downgrade. Although, I had no problem with installing that with a fair amount of packages installed.

Comment: that's a usual problem when you don't have aspcud. Many times it downgrades everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, first of all your don't have any active targets in your `_oasis` file. What I mean, is that OASIS is about building exectuables and libraries. You haven't described either. That means, that your `BuildDepends` doesn't have any effect, since it has only sense for `Library` and `Executable` entries. So, a first approximation would be the following:

```
OASISFormat: 0.4
Name:        Playground
Version:     0.1.0
Synopsis:    OCaml playground
Authors:     Andrea Ferretti
License:     Apache-2.0
BuildTools:   ocamlbuild
BuildDepends: irmin.unix, lwt.unix

Executable "example"
  Path: .
  MainIs: example.ml
  CompiledObject: best
```

> Doing so, I end up with Irmin version 0.8.3. Unfortunately, I cannot
>   follow their examples, because apparently Irmin is at version 0.9.4,
>   and it looks like the API has changed. So, I would like to start a
>   clean project having as dependency just Irmin 0.9.4

If you got a version that is not the newest, then you can try to persuade opam constraint solver, that you really need that specific version, like:

```
 opam install irmin.0.9.4 git cohttp
```

Also, opam internal constraint solver isn't very sophisticated, so make sure that you have aspcud installed on your system. The following will install the latest opam with aspcud on a fresh ubuntu installation:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:avsm/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --yes install opam
```

> What is the simplest way to set up a clean project that depends on Irmin 0.9.4, being sure that it is self-contained (it will not rely on
>   preinstalled libraries other than those installed by the build
>   process)?

Well, simplicity is a matter of personal opinion. For example, you can do the same without any oasis at all, just using `opam` file, where you set your `build` field, just to `["ocamlbuild"; "-use-ocamlfind"; "-pkgs irmin.unix,lwt.unix"; "example.native"]`, but how well it will scale...

Comment: Thank you, you are being really helpful!